# Hide an ASP.NET Menu Item

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms application with a Menu control. How does one hide a particular menu item via code? I've seen a few articles pointing out how to do it with ASP.Net membership/roles-based security, but this particular use case has nothing to do with that. I simply need a way to programmatically remove a menu item from code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doh! Ok, I figured it out. The correct syntax is (VB.Net):

```
mnuMyMenu.Items.Remove(mnuMyMenu.Items(1))
```

Answer (score 10):

It would be more straight forward to use

```
myMenu.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

This will remove the first menuitem

```
myMenu.Items[0].ChildItems.RemoveAt(1);
```

This will remove the second child of the fist menuitem

```
myMenu.Items[0].ChildItems[1].ChildItems.RemoveAt(1)
```

This will remove the second child of the second child of the fist menuitem

Answer (score 1):

```
myMenu.Items(0).ChildItems.Remove(myMenu.Items(0).ChildItems(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a menu item by the menu item Text property, you can use:

```
myMenu.Items.Remove(myMenu.FindItem("Item Text"))
```