# how can I hide and unhide the menues in menupath with asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to hide and unhide the menus in menupath by user access ,how can I do this?I mean I want that some users can see just some part of menus and other part should hide from them

Comment: hey try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430573/hide-an-asp-net-menu-item

Answer (score 2):

You should probably implement role based security with Forms Authentication.

```
if(user.IsInRole("Admin")) ShowMenu();
```

Here's a good article on the subject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication

Comment: where can I write this?I want to manage my treeview by users access

Comment: Implementing Role based security is not a trivial thing and there are many ways to accomplish it. I suggest reading the article in the Answer and the article on MSDN library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shz8h065(v=vs.90).aspx