# how can i hide/remove sub menu item from menu list

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server"  Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px"
    <asp:MenuItem Text="DashBoard"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Project">
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Config Project"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Task"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>

    <asp:MenuItem Text="Employees">
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="EMS"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="TimeSheet">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Period"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Report"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem
</asp:menu>
```

I am new in C#..how can i hide Task,Report menu items from menu list on page load ,considering this menu  in master page.I tried searching for similar question but didn't get right solution!

Comment: Give the MenuItem you want to hide an ID, access it from the codebehind, set it to invisible. I'm rusty which is why I didn't post this as an answer, but I think that's the general process. You may have to specify your .cs file as the codebehind in the ASP file. Google for C# codebehind

Comment: Maybe this related question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939114/541432

Comment: @KyleM Menuitem dont have any id

Comment: @elvin  through your provided link m able to remove/hide first menu items i.e Dashboard,Employee,Project but not there sub items

Comment: This is focused on removing, but you can see how you can access children of children in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430573/hide-an-asp-net-menu-item - so something like `Menu1.Items[1].ChildItems[1].Hidden = true;` - it isn't very flexible, but it'll work.

Comment: here is the solution  - 
Concept - 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.childitems.aspx                  
Through db  -  
http://www.codeshode.com/2011/07/display-hierarchical-data-with-menu.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*here is the solution -*

**Concept** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.childitems.aspx

**Through db** - http://www.codeshode.com/2011/07/display-hierarchical-data-with-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for reference, here is the solution that I use:

```
var menuItems = NavigationMenu.Items;
var projectMenuItem = menuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().First(p => p.Text == "Project");
var subItem = projectMenuItem.Cast<MenuItem>().First(p => p.Text == "Task");
projectMenuItem.ChildItems.Remove(subItem);
```

It's not pretty, but it works. Improvements welcome.